# Send XML data with Volley Android library

Tags: android, xml, http, post, android-volley

I would like to make a simple POST request to my server with XML formatted data in the requests' body using Volley Library. 
Is it possible to achieve that using StringRequest ? 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to use `StringRequest` for custom body. But you can either extend `StringRequest` or `Request` to override `getBody()` method.

Here is easiest way to do this:

```
public class CustomBodyStringRequest extends StringRequest {
    private final String requestBody;

    public CustomBodyStringRequest(String url, String requestBody, Response.Listener<String> listener,
                                   Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, listener, errorListener);
        this.requestBody = requestBody;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        byte[] body = null;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(this.requestBody)) {
            try {
                body = requestBody.getBytes(getParamsEncoding());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + getParamsEncoding(), e);
            }
        }

        return body;
    }
}
```

You might also want to override `getBodyContentType()` with something like `application/xml`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if I understand, the requestBody parameter is the stringified xml data ?

Comment: Yes, you can specify stringified xml data. Actually it will send any text data as is to server in request body. I thought you want to use `StringRequest` in such way. If you want to generate xml or make it more suitable for xml request you can extend Request and use DOM parser to generate xml from Map, List, etc.