# How to pass RAW body to the API using volley android

Tags: android, android-volley

[image]I am trying to POST body with my api of XML type. Please have a look at the body below! I have no clue how to pass xml body with the api

```
<passwordQuestions>
   <passwordQuestion question="security.question.childhood.nickname" answer="nickname"/>
   <passwordQuestion question="security.question.father.middleName" answer="father.middleName"/>
   <passwordQuestion question="security.question.oldestSibling.middleName" answer="oldestSibling.middleName"/>
</passwordQuestions>

type: 
Content-Type text/xml
```

This is my code need to add body here!

```
public void setSeqQns(String oldAPIEmail, String token,String appKey, String mLocale, String firstQuestion, String firstAnswer,
                          String secondQuestion, String secondAnswer, String thirdQuestion, String thirdAnswer,
                          final Action1<String> onUpdateSetAnswerSuccess, final Action1<String> onUpdateSetAnswerFail) {

        if(userId == null){
            Log.e(TAG, "userId is null");
            Observable<String> observable = Observable.just("userId is null");
            observable.subscribe(onUpdateSetAnswerFail);
            return;
        }

        String url = BASE_URL + Util.addUseridToUri(URI_SET_ANSWER, userId);

        Response.Listener<String> listener =
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Update seq qns response: "+ response);
                        Observable<String> observable = Observable.just(response);
                        observable.subscribe(onUpdateSetAnswerSuccess);
                    }
                };

        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                String errorCode = null;

                if (error.networkResponse != null) {
                    Map<String, String> headers = error.networkResponse.headers;
                    if (headers != null) {
                        errorCode = headers.get(PulseAPIConstants.HEADER_XIcErrorCode);
                        Log.e(TAG, "received error code: " + errorCode);
                    }
                }

                // observes this API request and will call the loginFailure action
                Observable<String> observable = Observable.just(errorCode);
                observable.subscribe(onUpdateSetAnswerFail);
            }
        };

        AuthenticatedGsonRequest<String> request = new AuthenticatedGsonRequest<>(
                Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                new TypeToken<String>() {}.getType(),
                null,
                listener,
                errorListener,
                oldAPIEmail,
                token,
                appKey,
                mLocale);

        addToRequestQueue(request, TAG_SET_ANSWER);
    }
```

I need to add xml(RAW body data) to the URI.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29660614  already asked question.

Comment: I was told we cannot parse XML with GSON. And problem is Gson can work only with Json. So for XML parsing you should use another tool. For example - XmlPullParser...                                                                                 Can anyone show me how to use XmlPullParser while using Volley!